# 2 ways to print a half-pyramid

Tags: c

I wrote this bit of C that prints a half-pyramid,

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

Here's the main body:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 4

void printrow(int threshold);

int main()
{
    int i, threshold;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        // threshold slides to the left with each iteration:
        // ===|
        // ==|=
        // =|==
        // |===
        threshold = SIZE - (i+1);

        printrow(threshold);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here are two different implementations of `printrow`. I'm not sure which is the better of the two.

Version one uses the threshold as a slider that divides the row into two smaller loops:

```
void printrow(int threshold)
{
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < threshold; j++)
        printf(" ");

    for (j = threshold; j < SIZE; j++)
        printf("*");

    printf("\n");
}
```

Version two runs a single loop and each iteration checks its position relative to the threshold when determining which character to print:

```
void printrow(int threshold)
{
    int j;
    char c;

    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        c = (j < threshold) ? ' ' : '*';
        printf("%c", c);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

This is a very small, simple program, but I'm curious which is the better approach, as I'm sure the same scenario can arise on a larger scale.

Comment: IMO:  the first option is better, because it is much easier to follow the code logic.   Please note: in the second for() statement of the first option, that 'j' will already be equal to 'threshold', so the first parameter of the second 'for()' statement can be omitted

Comment: @user3629249 I'm going to change the ternary in version two to an if-else, but you're probably right nonetheless. Also, that's an interesting point omitting the first parameter in the second for() statement. I'll do that.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @user3629249 that should be an answer

Comment: @Vogel612 My bad. I looked at the rules you linked, and yeah, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like your version one better - in that you can break it up into even smaller pieces. Split out the printing of repeated characters:

```
void print_repeat(char c, int n) {
    while (n--) {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

So that printing a row just calls that twice:

```
void print_row(int row_num, int size) {
    print_repeat(' ', size - (row_num + 1));
    print_repeat('*', row_num + 1);
    printf("\n");
}
```

And printing the whole pyramid just calls that in a loop:

```
void print_pyramid(int size) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        print_row(i, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

per the suggestion from vogel612, I made my comment into an answer.

IMO: the first option is better, because it is much easier to follow the code logic.

Please note: in the second for() statement of the first option, that 'j' will already be equal to 'threshold', so the first parameter of the second 'for()' statement can be omitted